# SALV - event when rowselection changed

Tags: abap, alv

Is there a chance to catch when a user clicks on another row?
I tried to do it with single click event and check if the row has changed. But this only fires on hotspots.

Comment: You can add buttons, which look like the grey selection column, in Your grid as the first column, and then react to "on_alv_button_click" IIRC, to deactivate the previous selection(s) and activate the current one ( by changing the symbol of the icon ). We did that very often to avoid the asynch behaviour, mkysoft is mentioning.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to get click event directly. You can use [**delayed_change_select**](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1620374) event for catch async.

Comment: i'm searching for a solution for SALV not ALV

Comment: @ThomasKlammer did you try to asking SALV with IDA? Old SALV already supported events, check sample program SALV_TEST_TABLE_EVENTS.